# Searching PHP/MySQL solution for latest comments

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently writing a little blog script. there are 2 tables in my database:

```
posts & comments
```

now I want to show the latest 10 comments like:

```
post 1 "do that" (last updated by a user comment)
post 2 "test" (*)
post 3 "hello" (*)
```

I dont want to show the comments, I only want to show the posts who are last updated by a user comment. also no double outputs.

table structure:

```
posts: id, date, title
comments: id, time, content
```

acutally no idea, how to solve that.
thank you!

Comment: You want to order by last user comment and not by post date?

Comment: What is the structure of your table ?

Comment: @rvbarreto yes I want it to order by last user comment

Answer (score 0):

You should learn basic sql...
You need a `SELECT` statement here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.date, p.title
FROM comments c
INNER JOIN posts p ON (p.id = c.post_id)
ORDER BY c.time DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you what to query data at the `posts` table and order it by data in `comments` table, you need a `JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM posts 
INNER JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = commnents.post_id 
GROUP BY posts.posts_id ORDER BY comments.comment_id DESC;
```

I'm considering that comments.comment_id is an autoincrement field, this way the DESC ordering will show the last comments added. This code will select all data in your post table, but will show starting by the last comment registrered. If you want, you can limit adding `LIMIT 3` in the end of your query.

Comment: autoincrement doesn't work if users can update their comments => order by time

Comment: @Rocki is right. If there is a "update time" field, you should order by it.

Comment: it just dont works.. it orders the posts by post id not by last comment from post

Comment: I was checking your table structure and I didn't saw any field that relates `comments` to `post`. How do you relate them? I was expecting one more field at the table `comments`: post_id

Comment: post = id, comment = post, also changed your query to posts.id = comments.post

Comment: can you paste the complete query you are using?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.date, p.title, p.author FROM comments c INNER JOIN posts p ON (p.id = c.post) ORDER BY c.date LIMIT 10`

Comment: I used TIMESTAMP for comments.date

Comment: you missed the DESC in the end of order, telling MySQL o order from the highest to the lowest. Try this:
`SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.date, p.title, p.author FROM comments c INNER JOIN posts p ON (p.id = c.post) ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: also used DESC. changed the order but selected it false. your query is also not working, but I found out that: the query isnt selecting the newest comment its selecting the comment id with the same id of the post. but a post can have more than one comment.

Comment: You want the query to return you the post content or the comment content?

Comment: If you want to receive comment data, you have to add it to SELECT, like this: `SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.date, p.title, p.author, c.content FROM comments c INNER JOIN posts p ON (p.id = c.post) ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts p INNER JOIN comments c ON p.id = c.post GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY MAX(c.id) DESC
```

was the solution.